# React + GraphQL + Realy

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, relayjs, relay

We are developing a backend API  (Graph QL + RealY) that will be consumed by aReact + Relay. This same api will be consumed by a mobile application too nativa OSX and Android.

Is it a common pattern to have this kind of architecture? As far As I know, consume graphQL+realy using reacty-realy is simple, but I don't know ehn using OSX/Android mobile.

Comment: Consider using React Native on Android (Relay works in React Native). As for OSX, did you mean macOS, or iOS? If the latter, React Native works there too.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be a POST request to the GraphQL endpoint, you will get a JSON result. Possibly it is not very best solution, but can get started.
For iOS you can try [Apollo](https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-ios).